# Stop Some svchost.exe programs

Tags: svchost

Hi I did Stop some SVCHOST PROGRAM and now my pc is messed up, it's stuck on a repairing loop and there's nothing I can do. Any ideas on how I can fix this? I did try some command prompt fix but ain't working the recovery is unattainable. Please help

Answer (score 0):

It is really not a good idea to shut services off (as you now are seeing).

> it's stuck on a repairing loop and there's nothing I can do.

**1.** Turn off, hold down the Shift Key and press the power button. Try to start in Safe Mode with Networking.

If so, open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator and run:

dism.exe /online  /cleanup-image  /startcomponentcleanup

dism.exe /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth

SFC /SCANNOW

Restart and see if normal mode works.

**2.** Go to the Media Creation Link  (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10 ) , make a bootable Windows 10 ISO (you may need to use Rufus to make it bootable).

Boot with this USB, back up your files to a USB Hard Drive, and then allow it to boot and see if you can reinstall Windows from it.